# Установить курсор в требуемое место (contenteditable)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть div с атрибутом *contenteditable="true"* в него вставляется <span class="value"></span>

Как мне поставить курсор в span?

В интернете нашёл такое решение,но оно почему то не работает.

```
 function moveToEnd(target) {   
 var rng, sel;   
 if ( document.createRange
 ) {
     rng = document.createRange();
     rng.selectNodeContents(target);
     rng.collapse(false);
     sel = window.getSelection();
     sel.removeAllRanges();
     sel.addRange( rng );   
  } else { // для IE нужно использовать TextRange
     var rng = document.body.createTextRange();
     rng.moveToElementText( target );
     rng.collapseToEnd();
     rng.select();   
  } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас div (*contenteditable="true"*) с дочерним элементом span, в который и надо поставить курсор при фокусе на родительский div. Если всё так, то [смотрите этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tnSmm/1/)

Comment: Вот, из Вашего примера сделал похожее на мой случай. Курсор вставляется не в span, а перед ним.